# PHPExcel......spreadsheet displays on webpage instead of downloading

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
<?php                      
if($_POST['export'])
{

require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php');
$qry="select accessed_Menus as menus,phone_number as phone,date_Accessed as timeAxed,sessionid as sessiondetails from access_trails where DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0 ,date_Accessed)) >= DATEADD(dd, -10, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, {fn NOW()})) order by date_Accessed desc";
$result=mssql_query($qry);
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$rowCount = 1;
while($row =mssql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['menus']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['phone']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $row['timeAxed']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $row['sessiondetails']);
    $rowCount++;
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Access Logs');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Access logs.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;


?>
```

Hi guys.....am using the code above to export data from a database to a spreadsheet....i able to retieve the data right but it only displays inside the loaded page. Am able to download a .xls file from my localhost though. Help

Comment: did you tried using different browser? My Chrome usually downloads all files, while FireFox just displays pdf documents in tab, though I did not noticed same thing with excel files

Comment: I have tried on chrome, FireFox and Internet explorer but still displays on webpage

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Mjukis.....See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php Code

```
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Expires: 0");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
 header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
 header("Content-Type: application/download");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.xls");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

echo strip_tags($_POST['tableData'],'<table><th><tr><td>');
```

Then use the javascript below to export

```
 $(function()      
        {
      $("#exportToExcel").click
         (function()                                   
          {
          var data='<table>'+$("#ReportTable").html().replace(/<a\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')+'</table>';
        $('body').prepend("<form method='post' action='php/exporttoexcel.php' style='display:none' id='ReportTableData'><input type='text' name='tableData' value='"+data+"' ></form>");
        $('#ReportTableData').submit().remove();
        return false;
       d}
      );
       }
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding these two headers, though I'm unsure it will help (I didn't tested it):

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides what's been pointed out you could also try adding these to the headers:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
```

Even though they don't seem to be needed for file to be prompted to download (the example I tried only has the same lines your code shows and it downloads without a problem in both IE 10 and Chrome)